# Create new lines in Showframe option from package Geometry

Tags: geometry

As in the title: can we create additional lines in the `showframe` option from the package `geometry` in order to create a new frame that suits our needs?

Essentially I am looking for a way to see how I am setting a cover page for a book. That is, I have frontcover, backcover, and spine all on the same page set with `geometry` (hence, it looks like a landscape page).

The problems is that I would like to see where the spine and where all margins (left, right, top, down) are in order to see how to properly compose the page.

PS: Observe that there is a question around where it is explained how to modify `geometry`to behave properly with the landscape option, but that does not work here, since I did not set it landscape.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement in brief? Else provide some sample image what you need to do...

Comment: You should definitely not use the geometry package to frame a page (which seems like a layout decision). Better try some overlays, which you could simply adjust to your needs. But without seeing what you're trying to do, it is hard to help you.

Comment: have a look at package fancybox https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancybox

Comment: @MadyYuvi: Here there are the needed explanations. I hope they help.

Comment: @TeXnician: As in the above comment. I edited the question. (Thanks for the advice, btw)

Comment: @Herbert Thanks a lot! According to Section 9 of the manual of the package, I have the feeling this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Kolmin Hope the package zwpagelayout.sty may use to you for creating cover pages...

Comment: @MadyYuvi From the first page of the documentation, this is **exactly** what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kolmin happy to hear, I'll keep my suggestion as answer for this question, please accept the same...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The package `zwpagelayout.sty` may fit for creating cover pages in LaTeX...please check the same...